# Why amd_pmu_v2_handle_irq being called when not using perf?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, amd-processor

[amd_pmu_v2_handle_irq](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/arch/x86/events/amd/core.c#L916) should be used to handle PMU overflow in AMD processor. When I use `perf top -ag` in the system, it is heavily called.

But when I use the `perf stat -a` command, there are fewer calls to this function, why is that? And why is there a very small number of related calls when I am not using any perf command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your system have the NMI watchdog timer enabled?  It programs a counter to raise an interrupt infrequently.  Check your `dmesg` for `NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.`

That message is what I see on Linux 6.5 on my Skylake, before `kernel/nmi_watchdog = 0` in my `sysctl` config file disables it so all four programmable counters per logical core are available.

---

Re: `perf stat -a` not needing many interrupts: total counts over the whole interval doesn't require statistical sampling.  It can program with the overflow limits as wide as possible.  When it wants to collect data at the end, it can read the counts out of each PMU counter (and add that to the `max * overflows` that got collected along the way).  Interrupts only need to happen for events that exceeded what the PMU counter could hold.

But `perf top` is like `perf record`, programming counters so they do overflow frequently, so it can record a sample (of process/program-counter) each time.  This gives it something to show every few seconds with hot spots across the process(es) being profiled, not just total counts at the end like `perf stat`.

`perf stat` is less intrusive, not interrupting the code being profiled much at all.  (`perf stat -I 1000` collects counter values every 1000 ms, but still doesn't need to know what happened within each interval.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found that using the `perf top` also results in different call frequencies when I specify different events. For example, when I use `-e cycles`, a large number of `amd_pmu_v2_handle_irq` calls occur, but when I use `-e cpu-clock`, almost no function calls occur. Since the former is hardware event and the latter is software event in `perf list`, can it be assumed that software events will be processed through software means rather than through hardware interrupt, and therefore `amd_pmu_v2_handle_irq` will not be called?

Comment: @Frontier_Setter: Right, of course.  The kernel can't program the PMU to raise interrupts for things that don't involve the PMU, that would be a contradiction.